# NHibernate aggregate not loading when getting list

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following class

```
public class Room
{
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set }
  public virtual string Name { get; set }
  public virtual Guid LocId { get; set }
  public virtual Location Loc { get; set; }
}
```

I start transaction and call Session.Save for a new entity and it writes it to the database correctly, but if I immediately call GetList() the list is returned with the Loc property assigned for all entities except for the new entity, but if I set the Loc before calling Save it is assigned for the new entity. Flush() does not solve the problem.  What am I missing, I would prefer not to get the Location to set it.

Comment: why are you mapping both the LocId and the Location?

Comment: Location was not part of the original map. I have added it so that that information will now be returned when GetList is called. I have not removed the LocId as I do not have the time to replace all its usages at this moment.

Comment: Exactly what is it that would set Location to reference a Location if you haven't specified it? What black magic is made in the database? Do you set LocId manually? And does that map to the same column in the database? Post your mapping file for this entity.

Comment: The LocId has existed on the Room class for while and the UI would set the LocId and then save. The UI used the LocId to select from a list of Locations when displaying.  We changed this to pull from the Location property now.  Everything is working except when Get or GetList is called within the same transaction even after a flush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping both `Loc` and `LocId` is an incorrect usage of NHibernate.

Use `room.Location = session.Load<Location>(locId)` to assign the Location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Session.Evict` function to evict your object from the session, otherwise it will load your in session object for the given id. I would, however, highly recommend that you remove the LocId property from your mapping.

Comment: @Thad, it's tough to say, without seeing your code, why you would be getting the exception. Possibly you're evicting before doing an update?

Comment: It appears that after I save I can call Session.Refresh(obj) and it corrects the problem.  Now to make time to remove LocId.